# how to access a newly created class in objective c

Tags: objective-c, class

I get the feeling that this is a very stupid question, but I cannot find an answer anywhere. I've created a new class in an XCode project called "Word", with its own .h and .m files, which inherits from NSString, and has its own declared instance variable, method, etc. How do I access it within the viewcontroller.h and .m files? I though it would just show up in the little suggestion box in XCode, like the pre-made classe, but it doesn't. How do I use my new class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#import "Word.h"
```

I will note that subclassing `NSString` is extremely uncommon and almost never what you mean to do. You probably meant to have `Word` have an `NSString` property.

Comment: I did it just so that I could call a method on a string that would return a NSMutableArray that contains the positions of all the instances of a certain character passed in as a parameter. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's a category method.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: It's not that uncommon -- they have a big section in the NSString documentation just for subclassing.

Comment: That doesn't make it common. They just documented it well because subclassing is legal but non-obvious. In all the products I've written, I never needed to. Even `NSAttributedString` doesn't subclass `NSString`. Subclassing `NSString` is for the case where you have a different way of managing internal storage. Has this come up in any of your projects? Read the first two paragraphs of the subclassing notes carefully. They explain why subclassing isn't usually what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

in your .h, at the top type `#import "` then start typing Word.h. It should autocomplete if the .h and .m files are in your project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the following to your ViewController.h

```
#import "Word.h"
```